# How can I merge two List<String> into a single List<String>?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, merge

I've saw some others questions about the same thing, but any of them fix my problem. Could be because I dont get the concept of it.

I have two `List<String>`:

```
List<String> PlatformInfo1 = new ArrayList
List<String> PlatformInfo2 = new ArrayList
```

Those List content some info from my database:

```
PlatformInfo1= [{"Nnodes":"163"}]
PlatformInfo2= [{"Commnet":"Windows Machine"}]
```

In order to interact with each element, I trying to include both array in one single object `List<String>` :

```
List<String> PlatformInfoGI = new ArrayList<String>();
PlatformInfoGI.addAll(PlatformInfo1);
PlatformInfoGI.addAll(PlatformInfo2);
```

The result which I'm getting is:

```
Value of PlatformInfoGI: [{"Nnodes":"163"},{"Commnet":"Windows Machine"}]
```

It would possible to do something to transform those `List<String>` into something like that:

```
 Value of PlatformInfoGI: [{"Nnodes":"163","Commnet":"Windows Machine"}]
```

`NOTE` the missing braces between elements.

What I wanted to get is a `List<String>` with one single element and different properties (Strings)

Comment: A List with one single element and different properties for this element, sounds like you need to creat a list of custom objects or a map of two Strings.

Comment: this code does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Use apache commons collections' [ListUtils.union(java.util.List list1, java.util.List list2)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#union%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)

> Returns a new list containing the second list appended to the first
>   list. The List.addAll(Collection) operation is used to append the two
>   given lists into a new list.

Comment: I got the same reult as using addAll `Value of PlatformInfoGI: [{"Nnodes":"163"},{"Commnet":"Windows Machine"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Am modifying slightly ,

List PlatformInfo1 = new ArrayList();

List PlatformInfo2 = new ArrayList();

```
    PlatformInfo1.add("Nnodes");
    PlatformInfo1.add("163");

    PlatformInfo2.add("Commnet");
    PlatformInfo2.add("Windows Machine");

    List<String> PlatformInfoGI = new ArrayList<String>();
    PlatformInfoGI.addAll(PlatformInfo1);
    PlatformInfoGI.addAll(PlatformInfo2);

    System.out.println(PlatformInfoGI);
```

This will print the result as : [Nnodes, 163, Commnet, Windows Machine]

P.S : May i know which IDE you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is case to show the result as:
`Value of PlatformInfoGI: [{"Nnodes":"163"},{"Commnet":"Windows Machine"}]`

for such result, it is a list contains 2 objects, while you had defined the list as :
`**List<String>** PlatformInfoGI = new **ArrayList<String>**();
PlatformInfoGI.addAll(PlatformInfo1);
PlatformInfoGI.addAll(PlatformInfo2);`

could should show me the result in your console by the sample code ?

Comment: This is the result in console: `Value of PlatformInfoGI: [{"Nnodes":"163"},{"Commnet":"Windows Machine"}]`